# Append element to 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I append an element to first or second element of a numpy array in python?
My code does not work.

I did like this:

```
my_num = np.array([[],[]])
my_num[0] = np.append(my_num[0],6)
print(my_num[0])
```

But my_num is empty.

Comment: @АлексейР I want to append elements to different indexed array. Your Code will add just to all of array

Comment: What result do you want to get?

Comment: `my_num` is a (2,0) shaped float dtype (check for yourself).  You can't `append` values to to that array, or change individual elements with append.  Better yet, don't use `np.append`.  It is not a list append clone.  Stick with lists - or use `numpy` arrays as documented.

Comment: @АлексейР like this: [[1,2],[3,4]]

Comment: Make a list `[[1,2],[3,4]]` and pass that to `np.array`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
my_num[0] = np.append(my_num[0],np.array([6]))
```

The second argument in append must be the same "shape" as the first (i.e., an array). See Numpy docs [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html).

Comment: Thank you. but it did not work. I did it by list.